# Nhibernate gives System.NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, left-join

I'm trying to do a left join between two table TaxInformation  and ThirdParty knowing
The join works correctly but when I try to do a left join i got the exception with the message:  '***System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.***'

```
 var TaxInformations = session.Query<TaxInformation>();

 var query = session.Query<ThirdParty>()
                                   .Where(tpa => tpa.ThirdPartySourceId == 1
                                  

var resultList = (from tpn in query
                                  join tti in TaxInformations on tpn.Id equals tti.ThirdPartyId into ttiLeft
                                  from ttiL in ttiLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                  select new ThirdParty()
                                  {
                                      Id = tpn.Id,
                                      LastName = tpn.LastName,
                                      FirstName = tpn.FirstName,
                                      DateOfBirth = tpn.DateOfBirth,
                                      LegalContactPostalAddressId = tpn.LegalContactPostalAddressId,
                                      BirthCityId = tpn.BirthCityId,
                                      BirthCityName = tpn.BirthCityName,
                                      Code = tpn.Code,
                                      ContactPostalAdress = tpn.ContactPostalAdress,
                                      TaxInformation = ttiL ?? null
                                  }).ToList();
  return resultList;




Mapping done via : 



public ThirdPartyTaxInformationMap()
        {
            this.Table("TaxInformation");
            this.Schema("dbo");
            this.Lazy(false);
            this.DynamicUpdate(true);
            this.DynamicInsert(true);           
            
            this.Id(x => x.Id, map => map.Generator(Generators.Identity));
            this.Property(x => x.ThirdPartyId);
            

            this.ManyToOne(
                x => x.Country,
                map =>
                {
                    map.Column("CountryId");
                    map.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                    map.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
                    map.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
                    map.Update(false);
                    map.Insert(false);
                }
                );
```

### -----------Mapping ThirdParty---------

```
public ThirdPartyMap()
        {
            this.Table("ThirdParty");
            this.Lazy(false);
            this.DynamicUpdate(true);
            this.DynamicInsert(true);
    
            this.Id(x => x.Id, map => map.Generator(Generators.Identity));
            this.Property(x => x.Code, map => map.Column("Code"));
            this.Property(x => x.ThirdPartySourceId);
            
    
            this.ManyToOne(
                x => x.ContactPostalAdress,
                map =>
                {
                    map.Column("LegalContactPostalAddressId");
                    map.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                    map.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
                    map.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
                    map.Update(false);
                    map.Insert(false);
                });
    
    
            #region Third Party Type
            ManyToOne(p => p.ThirdPartyType, m =>
            {
                m.Class(typeof(ThirdPartyType));
                m.Column("ThirdPartyTypeId");
                m.NotNullable(false);
                m.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
                m.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
                m.Update(true);
                m.Insert(true);
            });
            #endregion
    
    
        }
```

The Call stack trace :

at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitGroupJoinClause(GroupJoinClause groupJoinClause, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.GroupJoinClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitBodyClauses(ObservableCollection`1 bodyClauses, QueryModel queryModel) at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel) at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.Visit() at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root, Nullable`1 rootReturnType)
at NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, Boolean filter)
at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Oddo.MAP.Server.Modules.Core.Business.ThirdPartyBusinessServices.FindAllThirdpartyNatural() in C:\projets\MAP_Old\Server\Modules\Core\Server.Modules.Core.Business\ThirdPartyBusinessServices.cs:line 251
at Oddo.MAP.Server.Modules.Core.Business.ThirdPartyBusinessServices.CheckMatchingForThirdParties(Boolean isThirdPartyNatural) in C:\projets\MAP_Old\Server\Modules\Core\Server.Modules.Core.Business\ThirdPartyBusinessServices.cs:line 565
at DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_IThirdPartyBusinessServices_fcf8cfddd9494f5898ae07beeb4a9d19.<CheckMatchingForThirdParties_DelegateImplementation>__2(IMethodInvocation inputs, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_IThirdPartyBusinessServices_fcf8cfddd9494f5898ae07beeb4a9d19.CheckMatchingForThirdParties(Boolean isThirdPartyNatural)
at Oddo.MAP.Host.Dedoublonnage.Console.AppBootstrapper.OnModulesLoaded() in C:\projets\MAP_Old\Host\Host.Dedoublonnage\Program.cs:line 78
at Oddo.Components.Hosting.Unity.WebApi.WebApiHostingUnityBootstrapper.Initialize()
at Oddo.MAP.Host.Dedoublonnage.Console.AppBootstrapper.Initialize() in C:\projets\MAP_Old\Host\Host.Dedoublonnage\Program.cs:line 43
at Oddo.MAP.Host.Dedoublonnage.Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projets\MAP_Old\Host\Host.Dedoublonnage\Program.cs:line 26

Comment: NHibernate version? Try with latest NHibernate 5.4

Comment: i'm using Nhibernate 5.2.0.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to use `.ToList()` with every query launched.
This will load all the data into memory so it will be a consuming task.
In order to minimize to load all the uncessary staff we should do a select where we pick up only needed attributes.

```
public IList<ThirdPartyNatural> FindAllThirdpartyNatural()
{
    var thirdPartyNaturals = DataAccessServicesProvider.Query<ThirdPartyNatural>().Where
            (tpa => tpa.ThirdPartySourceId == 1
&& (tpa.ClosingDate == null || (tpa.ClosingDate.HasValue && tpa.ClosingDate.Value.Date > DateTime.Today)));

    var thirdPartyTaxInformations = DataAccessServicesProvider.Query<ThirdPartyTaxInformation>();

    var resultList = (from thirdPartyNatural in thirdPartyNaturals.Select(th => new { th.Id, th.LastName, th.FirstName, th.DateOfBirth, th.LegalContactPostalAddressId, th.BirthCityId, th.BirthCityName, th.Code, th.ContactPostalAdress }).ToList()
                      join thirdPartyTaxInformation in thirdPartyTaxInformations.Select(tax => new { tax.ThirdPartyId, tax.OpeningDate, tax.Code, tax.TaxCode }).ToList()
                          on thirdPartyNatural.Id equals thirdPartyTaxInformation.ThirdPartyId into thirdPartyList

                      from item in thirdPartyList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new ThirdPartyNatural
                      {
                          Id = thirdPartyNatural.Id,
                          LastName = thirdPartyNatural.LastName,
                          FirstName = thirdPartyNatural.FirstName,
                          DateOfBirth = thirdPartyNatural.DateOfBirth,
                          LegalContactPostalAddressId = thirdPartyNatural.LegalContactPostalAddressId,
                          BirthCityId = thirdPartyNatural.BirthCityId,
                          BirthCityName = thirdPartyNatural.BirthCityName,
                          Code = thirdPartyNatural.Code,
                          ContactPostalAdress = thirdPartyNatural.ContactPostalAdress,
                          TaxCode = item?.TaxCode
                      }).OrderBy(ps => ps.LastName).ToList();
    return resultList;
}
```